# Symfony Forms: CollectionType - Don't transform null to empty array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

We are using Symfony Forms for our API to validate request data. At the moment we are facing a problem with the `CollectionType` which is converting the supplied value `null` to an empty array `[]`.

As it is important for me to differentiate between the user suppling `null` or an empty array I would like to disable this behavior.

I already tried to set the `'empty_data'` to `null` - unfortunately without success.

This is how the configuration of my field looks like:

```
$builder->add(
    'subjects',
    Type\CollectionType::class,
    [
        'entry_type'    => Type\IntegerType::class,
        'entry_options' => [
            'label'     => 'subjects',
            'required'  => true,
            'empty_data' => null,
        ],
        'required'   => false,
        'allow_add'  => true,
        'empty_data' => null,
    ]
);
```

The form get's handled like this:

```
$data = $apiRequest->getData();

$form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, $data, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'allow_extra_fields' => true]);
$form->submit($data);

$formData = $form->getData();
```

**The current behavior is:**

Input `$data` => `{ 'subjects' => null }`

Output `$formData` => `{ 'subjects' => [] }`

**My desired behavior would be:**

Input `$data` => `{ 'subjects' => null }`

Output `$formData` => `{ 'subjects' => null }`

Comment: does your form have a `data_class`? can you, just for testing purposes, remove the data class and see if the subjects are still an array or are then null?

Comment: @Jakumi The form actually has no `data_class` 
I just create the form like this and then call the submit function:
`$form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, null, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'allow_extra_fields' => true]);
$form->submit($data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries I finally found a solution by creating a [From Type Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) in combination with a [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

By creating this form type extension I'm able to extend the default configuration of the `CollectionType` FormType. This way I can set a custom build `ModelTransformer` to handle my desired behavior.

This is my Form Type Extension:

```php
class KeepNullFormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [CollectionType::class];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->addModelTransformer(new KeepNullDataTransformer());
    }

}
```

This one needs to be registered with the `'form.type_extension'` tag in your service.yml:

```yml
PrivateApiBundle\Form\Extensions\KeepNullFormTypeExtension:
    class: PrivateApiBundle\Form\Extensions\KeepNullFormTypeExtension
    tags: ['form.type_extension']
```

> Please note that you still use the `CollectionType` in your FormType and not the `KeepNullFormTypeExtension` as Symfony takes care about the extending...

In the `KeepNullFormTypeExtension` you can see that I set a custom model transformer with `addModelTransformer` which is called `KeepNullDataTransformer`

The `KeepNullDataTransformer` is responsible for keeping the input `null` as the output value - it looks like this:

```php
class KeepNullDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    protected $initialInputValue = 'unset';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($data)
    {
        $this->initialInputValue = $data;
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($data)
    {
        return ($this->initialInputValue === null) ? null : $data;
    }
}
```

And that's it - this way a supplied input of the type `null` will stay as `null`.

More details about this can be found in the linked Symfony documentation:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html